# Are propositions of logic for the tractarian Wittgenstein "sinnlos satze"?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein

For the tractarian Wittgenstein propositions of logic did not have a meaning because logic was only an instrument.

Given that he divided meaningless propositions into *unsinnig satze* (nonsense) and *sinnlos satze* (meaningless), which category do the propositions of logic belong to?

Is it legitimate to say that propositions of logic are *sinnlos*, whereas propositions of metaphysics are *unsinnig*?

Comment: I made some edits to hopefully clarify the question. I am curious about this as well now that you've raised the question. +1

Comment: See the post ; [Making 'sense' of Wittgenstein's senselessness / nonsense distinction in the Tractatus](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51115/making-sense-of-wittgensteins-senselessness-nonsense-distinction-in-the-tra)

Answer (score 5):

For the early Wittgenstein, logical propositions (tautologies/contradictions) are senseless, but not nonsense. He says this explicitly in the *Tractatus*:

> 4.461 Propositions show what they say: tautologies and contradictions show that they say nothing. 
>   A tautology has no truth-conditions, since it is unconditionally true: and a contradiction is true on no condition.
>   Tautologies and contradictions lack sense.
>   (Like a point from which two arrows go out in opposite directions to one another.)
>   (For example, I know nothing about the weather when I know that it is either raining or not raining.)
>
> 4.4611 Tautologies and contradictions are not, however, nonsensical. They are part of the symbolism, much as ‘0’ is part of the symbolism of arithmetic.